# Can you print variables that are dynamically generated?

Tags: variables, printing, autohotkey

I am trying to setup a program that takes user input for database ddl generation. I have it working to the point where it can ask a user for the name of the table, the number of columns and any attributes that might be needed. The problem comes when I try to print a string that includes the variables used for the column names. Due to trying to let users have as many columns as they want I used variables similar to this newvar(number that increases every time you enter a column name). This works fine and I can get the values if i do send %newvar1% but it doesn't work to do send newvar%increasing number%. I need to know if this is possible or if I'm just missing something obvious. Also I don't have the code with me but I can post it once I get back to my main computer.

I have tried quite a few things like, send %newvar%%number%, send newvar%number%, othervar = newvar%number% send %othervar%.

I'll show some once I have access to it in about 2 hours.

I expect to be able to output names for increasing variables using an ever increasing number. Class is starting I'll clarify some things later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lone percent `%` beginning the first argument for the send command to achieve what you want. This will make everything after it to be evaluated (up to the next comma). Here is an example:

```
f1::
newvar1 := "This " , newvar2 := "is just a " , newvar3 := "test."
Loop , 3
    Send , % newvar%A_Index%
Return
```

See: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Language.htm#-expression

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what I needed!